# Nestjs how to pass mongodb dependency to user.module.ts unit test

Tags: unit-testing, mongoose, dependency-injection, nestjs

I am trying to preform tests to the module.ts file in order to increase coverage.
I have this is my module file:

```
import { Module, MiddlewareConsumer, NestModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { UserController } from './user.controller';
import { UserSchema } from './schemas/user.schema';
import { Eauth } from './middlewares/eauth.middlewares';
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: 'User',
        schema: UserSchema,
      },
    ]),
    HttpModule,
  ],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService],
})

// // Register Eauth middleware
export class UserModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(Eauth).forRoutes(UserController);
  }
}
```

This is my user.module.spec.ts file content:

```
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { UserModule } from './user.module';

describe('ThingsModule', () => {
  it('should compile the module', async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [UserModule],
    }).compile();

    expect(module).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

This is the error I receive:

```
  ● ThingsModule › should compile the module

    Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserModel (?). Please make sure that the argument DatabaseConnection at index [0] is available in the MongooseModule context.

    Potential solutions:
    - If DatabaseConnection is a provider, is it part of the current MongooseModule?
    - If DatabaseConnection is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within MongooseModule?
      @Module({
        imports: [ /* the Module containing DatabaseConnection */ ]
      })
```

What does this mean? as far as I understand I need to inject the mongoose model dependency.
Am I correct? if so, How can I inject the missing dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that in the module.spec.ts file the `userMoudule` dependency was imported as `imports` and not as `providers` as it should be.
the reason for that is that

This is how the spec file looks now:

```
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { UserModule } from './user.module';

describe('UserModule', () => {
  it('should compile the module', async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [UserModule],
    }).compile();
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(module).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```